# Showing this Galois group is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_4$ by examining the nature of its automorphisms.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, field-theory, galois-theory

Say we have the polynomial $x^6-1$, I want to find the Galois group of this over $\Bbb Q$.

$x^6-1=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)$

And using the quadratic formula on the two quadratic polynomials we get

$x=\tfrac{^+_-1^+_-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Which (together with $^+_-1$) are the 6th roots of unity

So a splitting field for $x^6-1$ over $\Bbb Q$ is $\Bbb Q(w)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3},i)$

where w is the 6th root of unity , so clearly the degree of the extension is 4.

Its also obvious that the extension is normal and separable so we have a Galois extension.

$\therefore |Gal(\Bbb Q(w)/\Bbb Q)|=|\Bbb Q(w): \Bbb Q|=4.$

Furthermore the minimum polynomial of $w$ ( $x^4+x^2+1$) has 4 roots

So $Gal(\Bbb Q(w)/\Bbb Q)\leq S_4$

So we know that the Galois group must be isomorphic to either the klein 4 group or the cyclic group $\Bbb Z_4$.

I know just intuitively it's $\Bbb Z_4$ but I'm a little stuck at showing that .

Of course we know that any $\sigma \in Gal(\Bbb Q(w)/ \Bbb Q)$ will map the roots of the min. poly of w to another root.

So say $\sigma:w \rightarrow w^2$

But the problem is this has order 3 not 4 ?

So why is this automorphism not working , how can I choose the correct automorphism ?

Edit: Because $x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$ we see that the min poly of $\tfrac{1^+_-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is $(x^2-x+1)$ and the min poly of {-1^+_-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Therefore any automorphism of the Galois group will map $\tfrac{1^+_-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\rightarrow \tfrac{1^+_-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\tfrac{-1^+_-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\rightarrow $\tfrac{-1^+_-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$$.

So the 4 automorphisms are :

$\sigma_1: \tfrac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\rightarrow \tfrac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}, \tfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} \rightarrow \tfrac{-1^+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$\sigma_2: \tfrac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\rightarrow \tfrac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}, \tfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} \rightarrow \tfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$\sigma_3: \tfrac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\rightarrow \tfrac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}, \tfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} \rightarrow \tfrac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$\sigma_4: \tfrac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\rightarrow \tfrac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}, \tfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} \rightarrow \tfrac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Testing all these elements we see that each has order two therefore the galois group is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$

Comment: @Servaes oh would it be instead that $\Bbb Q(w)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3}i)$?

Comment: How can you have four automorphisms in a group of order $2$? Note, for example, that $\sigma_2$ sends $\omega$ to $\bar \omega$ and $\omega-1$ to $\omega-1$ and these are inconsistent. (I'm using $\omega$ for the first of the roots listed in each of the "automorphisms")

Comment: @MarkBennet sorry my mistake in my edit I had meant write Z_4 , but then servaes pointed out that the group actually is Z_2, which I understand in terms of the extension being quadratic, I think from everything here that basically there are two elements in the group , the id and the automorphism which performs complex conjugation and this non trivial automorphism works on the roots of either min poly to send it to the other root

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not true that $\Bbb{Q}(\omega)=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},i)$. In fact $\Bbb{Q}(\omega)=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, which is a quadratic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$, so the Galois group is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.

The map given by $\sigma:\ \omega\ \mapsto\ \omega^2$ is not even an automorphism. In stead, the only nontrivial automorphism is given by $\omega\ \mapsto\ \omega^5$.

Comment: You beat me to it, I commented when I realised what my mistake was, thank you though :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I deleted my attempt - tired. I did want to record that in the case of polynomials $x^4+ax^2+b$ it is always possible to build a splitting field from extensions of degree $2$ so you never get a factor $3$ in the order/degree.

Comment: @MarkBennet I edited my question based off your comment but I see it was deleted , is my new attempt okay , the automorphism $w \rightarrow w^5$ has order 2 but it only does the mapping $  \tfrac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\rightarrow \tfrac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ what about the mapping $, \tfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} \rightarrow \tfrac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ ?

Comment: @servaes could you take a look at my new edit and comment please, still just a little stuck :/ although I do see why it should be a galois group os size two now because the extension is quadratic I'm confused as to why despite the fact there are two quadractics in the factoring of $x^6-1$ we only consider the roots of one of them ?

Comment: If $\sigma(\tfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2})=\tfrac{1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ for example, then
$$\sigma(\tfrac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2})=\sigma(-1+\tfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2})=\sigma(-1)+\sigma(\tfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2})=-1+\tfrac{1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}=\tfrac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}.$$
You cannot choose the images of the roots independently. In fact, the four roots are $\omega$, $\omega^2$, $\omega^4$ and $\omega^5$. Because $\sigma(\omega^k)=\sigma(\omega)^k$, any automorphism is determined by where it maps $\omega$.

Comment: The obvious automorphism is complex conjugation, because each quadratic has a pair of conjugate roots. To identify this by powers of $\omega$ you need to identify which of the quadratics $\omega$ is a root of. If $\omega^3=1$ then you can send $\omega$ to $\omega^2$. If $\omega^2=-1$ you get $\omega^5$.

Comment: Stupid question, but how do you simply see that $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)=\mathbb{Q}(-\sqrt{3})$ ? I mean $\omega^2$ is not an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$, or?

Comment: @Diger No, $\Bbb{Q}(\omega)=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$. And this should be pretty clear from the fact that the powers of $\omega$ are of the form $\tfrac{\pm1\pm\sqrt{-3}}{2}$.

Comment: Ah... Yeah true.